# Adding a plus sign in a circuit diagram

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to place a plus sign above my voltage source in circuitikz but I just can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas?
[image: voltage source]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
draw (0,0)  to [vsourcesin]  (0,2)
;

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

This is the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)
to[vsourcesin,i=$i$] (0,4);
\draw (-0.3,2.6) node{$+$};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: plus]

Comment: And where is the code, by which you try to make provided image?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165177/including-signs-to-battery-in-circuitikz.

Comment: And use `+` sigh at sinus generator, what sense have this? I suggest rethinking what you actually need ...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use absolute coordinates, you can use the `name=...` option to specify a node name,  Note, the anchors n,e,w,s etc. are assigned before the component is rotated.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)  to[vsourcesin,name=VS]  (0,2);
\node[above left,inner sep=0pt] at (VS.e) {\tiny $+$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: label]

---

From the source code I see the list of anchors include `left`, `right`, `above`, `below`, `a` and `b`, but they are still rotated like  `ne` and `sw`.  Other anchors like `in`, `out`, `up` and `down` are component dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is on one hand unclear and in a sense of electrical engineering wrong and in another it is duplicate to question as mentioned Steven S. Seglets in his comment. Anyway, see if this solution is satisfactory to you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
    \PreviewEnvironment{circuitikz}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw   (1,0) -- 
        (0,0) to [V, v=$V$, i=$i$]  (0,3)
              -- (1,3);
\draw   (4,0) --
        (3,0) to [V]  (3,3)
              -- (4,3);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My book uses this labeling convention. I guess it is not in standard use.  Your solution is all right but I would prefer my original picture with a +.

Comment: My sketch is shows american way of electronic circuits  drawing and such it is not according to international standard ...  I wondering, why exist standards ( IEC for example), if the books doesn't respect them. Your `+` sign you can easy add as separate node to  voltage source symbol.